# What is wrong in this assignment

Tags: python, list, initialization, tuples

```
_read_ = {}
_read_['time_list'] = [6000, 4000, 2000]
def abc(_read_): 
    time_list = _read_['time_list'] 
    for i in range (0, 10):
        if len(time_list) != 0:
            print (time_list.pop())
        else:
            time_list = _read_['time_list'] 

abc(_wear_)
```

I'm trying to reinitialize the list(line 10), when it gets empty, with the same values as its being done in line 5
I was expecting the print to be

```
2000
4000
6000
2000
4000
6000
2000
4000
6000
2000
```

but I don't get anything after the first series is popped out i.e. the list does not get reinitialized

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: An assignment doesn't make a copy.

Comment: Because in Python `time_list` is reference of `_read_['time_list']`, so when you change `_read_['time_list']` it also changes the value of `time_list` and vice versa

Comment: First why there is a loop from `(0, 10)`, and you popping all the elements of `time_list` out and when the length is zero, re init by `_read_['time_list']`. What are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Thanks @n33rma. Yes, that's the correct reason. I fixed it by using time_list = _read_['time_list'].copy() function.     I cannot write the whole context due to copyright issues but then the summary is, the code reinitializes the list, whenever it will gets empty with original values.